# When user hits back button, css element that's styled by previous click is still styled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a CSS style set for an element when someone clicks or hovers on the element. On mobile Safari, when users click it to go to a new page but then hit the browser's back button, it's still shown in the "click" color. Is there a way to stop this?

```
.button:hover, .button:active
{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: do you have a `:visited` color defined somewhere? - also, we need more code, there is not enough information in your question to formulate a complete answer (hint: add a [mcve])

Comment: @ochi I don't have the visited css anywhere. but wouldn't that make it so it doesn't turn red on press anymore?

Comment: Not necessarily, if you define the `:active` and the `:visited` differently, they will look different.

Comment: @ochi yes, but then after it's been visited, it won't show the active color anymore on presses or hovers: https://jsfiddle.net/h87pLcyg/

Comment: Yup, it will be different (on button press, i.e. when active - since on hover it has a different colour setting)

Comment: @ochi you misunderstand. After you visit the link, active and hover styles no longer work on the link because visited takes precedence. so active and hover only work once and then stop working if you have a visited style

Comment: oh!, then you can add `!important` at the end to give it more precedence.  see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91bn8Lek/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mobile safari browser has this typical way of handling pages i.e., once it redirects to new page it will cache the page state itself or snapshot of page and when you come back it will show that snapshot directly. I too faced these kind of issues but i didn't found a rigid solution.

I solved the issue by changing the color of button back to whatever(default) in the click handler itself and then performed my remaining actions in your case it is redirection. Hope it will help you as a quick fix for the issue

Comment: Thanks, i think JavaScript is the only solution

Comment: Is the issue reproduceable only on Safari mobile? and not on other browsers?

Comment: As per my knowledge its not reproducible in any other browsers other than mobile safari. I verified in mobile chrome and default browser of android.

Comment: Nice Thanks. how about chrome ?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `:visited` selector:

```
.button:hover, .button:active
{
    color: red;
}

.button:visited
{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I understood that he wants the button to stop looking like the `:active` state (but maybe I read the question wrong)